# TSC cannot find name of Global Object

Tags: node.js, typescript

In my typescript code I am trying to access the `__dirname` global object: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html

I am seeing a compile error: `TS2304:Cannot find name '__dirname'.`
I can run the code without any issue. How can I get `tsc` to compile without error?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

In `tsconfig.json` add `"node"` to `compilerOptions.types`.

Example:

```
{
 "compilerOptions": {
  ...
  "types": [
    "node"
  ]
  ...
  }
}
```

Then run `npm install @types/node --save-dev`

Comment: Simply running the `npm install` command you listed was enough for me. Didn't need to modify `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: For React Native 0.70 I just had to add the above config to `tsconfig.json`, i.e. no need to add the `@types/node`package