# How to solve "error TS2304: Cannot find name 'global' " during TypeScript compilation?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, build, gulp

I am trying to compile *TypeScript 3.2.2* from source code. The Node.js version I use is 11.13.0.
Due to errors in some *"node_modules"*, I had to install older versions of them using ***npm install***.
Next, I run ***gulp local*** (*jake* doesn't work at all in this case and I don't understand why). And after some time I get the following results:

```
Finished 'built/local/diagnosticMessages.generated.json' after 39 ms
Finished 'built/local/enu/diagnosticMessages.generated.json.lcg' after 2.37 s
Starting 'localize'...
Finished 'localize' after 3.47 μs
src/compiler/inspectValue.ts(86,57): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'global'.
```

I do not know all the subtleties, but in other discussions it is written that the problem is in *node*. I tried running ***npm install @types/node*** or ***npm install @types/node@4.2.19***, but the problem didn't change.

The line where an error occurred is:

```
const map = createMap<AnyConstructor>();
        for (const { key, value } of getEntriesOfObject(global)) {
            if (typeof value === "function" && typeof value.prototype === "object" && value !== Object) {
                map.set(key, value as AnyConstructor);
            }
        }
        return map;
```

There is no mention of *global* anywhere else in the text. I don't know TypeScript or JavaScript at all, so I can't say in which modules it searches and what exactly it should find. I can't use the TypeScript version above, I need to build exactly 3.2.2.
I will be grateful for any help in this.

Comment: Most likely this an node error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45445976/tsc-cannot-find-name-of-global-object

Comment: Yes, I saw it. I tried to change the _config.json_ file in _src/compiler_ and run **npm install @types/node --save-dev**. But it didn't give any results